# Porting from Windows to Linux. Assembler command translation

Tags: assembly, system-calls, gnu-assembler, att

I have recently started learning porting from Windows to Linux. I've been translating program from Intel syntax to AT&T syntax also converting it from x32 to x64. And since I'm new enough to assembler and especially AT&T I've faced some troubles while porting. Just to mention: I'm intentionally not using `.intel_syntax` directive.

**So I got stucked with translating these commands:**

```
RTLWriteIntegerBuffer: TIMES 3 DB 0x90,0x8D,0x40,0x00
```

followed by:

```
LEA EDI,[OFFSET RTLWriteIntegerBuffer+ECX-1]
```

Another one:

```
LEA EBX,[EDX+'0']
```

One more:

```
ReadCharInited: DB 0
CMP BYTE PTR ReadCharInited,0
```

Another question is: **Is there 1:1 mapping between AT&T syntax and Intel syntax?** Or are there specific Intel commands that are not supported in AT&T?

And maybe someone knows about functions like this:

```
HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE=1
HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS=4
HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY=8
...
INVOKE HeapAlloc,EAX,HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS+HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY+HEAP_CREATE_ALIGN_16,4194332
```

This one is probably Borland Turbo Assembler-specific way to call `kernel32.dll`'s `HeapAlloc`, but I'm not sure. **Can it be translated to `fallocate` syscall?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of `times` you can use `.rept` or type it out. For the others read about at&t memory reference syntax. `fallocate` is totally different from `HeapAlloc`.

Comment: Do you really need AT&T syntax?  Wouldn't it be a lot easier to port to gas's `.intel_syntax noprefix` (which is very similar to MASM), or to NASM syntax?  Then you'd just have to change the system calls / ABI, not every instruction.  (See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for links to assembler manuals)

Comment: It's so easy to get wrong by hand that I'd suggest assembling with MASM, then disassembling with `objdump -drwC` and porting the directives and comments over to the disassembly.  I think objdump has options to get something closer to being being ready for assembler input, or use Agner Fog's objconv disassembler which does make output that can be assembled again.

Comment: For an introduction to AT&T-syntax, you might want to [RTFM](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dDependent.html#i386_002dDependent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When talking about "AT&T syntax" versus "Intel syntax", it normally only refers to the difference between instruction mnemonics and operand ordering and format.

So, for example, this is an instruction in AT&T syntax:

```
movl $1, (%esi)
```

and this is the same instruction using Intel syntax:

```
mov  DWORD PTR [esi], 1
```

For every instruction representable in Intel syntax, there's an equivalent representation in AT&T syntax for that instruction.

Since there's no AT&T assembler and no Intel assembler any more, the directives (everything other than the instructions) are a different matter. The GNU assembler (GAS) supports AT&T and Intel syntax, but only its own directives, which are an extension of the directives used by the AT&T assembler. Microsoft's MASM supports only Intel syntax but also only its own directives, which are an extension of the original Intel assembler's. There isn't always a direct equivalent from one assembler's directives to another assembler's. In some cases the fact that they use different object file formats may prevent finding any way of implementing the functionality of a directive in a different assembler using a different object file format.  (Or even the same assembler using a different format, as can be the case with the GNU assembler.)

As an example, here's some GAS directives:

```
.rept 3
.byte 0x90, 0x8D, 0x40, 0x00
.endr
```

And here are the equivalent MASM directives:

```
REPT 3
DB 90h, 8Dh, 40h, 00h
ENDM
```

But there's no MASM equivalent of the following GAS directive, because it's specific to the ELF object format, which MASM doesn't support:

```
.protected foo
```

On the other hand there's no direct equivalent to the following MASM directive, because GAS doesn't support any complex high level language directives:

```
INVOKE HeapAlloc,EAX,HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS+HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY+HEAP_CREATE_ALIGN_16,4194332
```

To port the former ELF-specific directive you'd have to redesign the application to deal with how Windows handles shared libraries.  To port the later MASM-specific directive you'd either have to create your own macro that did the work of figuring out how to pass the all the arguments correctly, or just manually write out all the assembly instructions necessary for this call according to the Linux x86-64 ABI.  (You'd also have to find an appropriate Linux function to call and pass a different set of arguments, but that's a separate issue from translating the directive itself.)

Some assemblers try to be compatible with other assemblers; for example Borland's TASM tries to be compatible with MASM, although it's an older version of MASM. So what works in TASM (in its default MASM mode) will usually work in MASM and vice versa.  Many assemblers, however, use essentially their own version of x86 assembly language.

For example, the code you've shown in your post seems to be using two different assembly language versions and can't be assembled by any single assembler.  Your first line of code uses the `TIMES` directive, but this directive is only supported by NASM, which doesn't use AT&T syntax nor Intel syntax.  It has its own instruction syntax, although it's not that different from Intel syntax. It also has its own incompatible set of directives, not based on anything in particular, like that `TIMES` directive you showed.

The rest of your code appears to be in MASM syntax. Except for the third line, it wouldn't assemble correctly with NASM (nor would the first line assemble correctly with MASM). I'm not sure if would assemble with TASM either, since the `INVOKE` directive was added in MASM 6.

Note that, given the nature of your code, it probably gains nothing by being written in assembly language and you might be far better off translating it into C, C++, or some other language you're more familiar with.

Comment: I'd +1 again for the suggestion to port to C instead of AT&T x86-64 asm with Linux system calls, after upvoting for the discussion of directives.  (I noticed the TIMES vs. INVOKE thing too, but wasn't sure that TIMES was NASM only).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with Windows, but let me try to help you anyway.

> ```
> RTLWriteIntegerBuffer: TIMES 3 DB 0x90,0x8D,0x40,0x00
> ```

The `DB` directive translates to `.byte` in the UNIX assembler, `TIMES` is supported in gas (as `.rept`) but I recommend to avoid it as it's not portable to other UNIX assemblers. So this snippet becomes

```
RTLWriteIntegerBuffer:
    .byte 0x90,0x8d,0x40,0x00
    .byte 0x90,0x8d,0x40,0x00
    .byte 0x90,0x8d,0x40,0x00
```

> ```
> LEA EDI,[OFFSET RTLWriteIntegerBuffer+ECX-1]
> ```

An Intel-style memory operand of the form `[disp+base+index*scale]` becomes `disp(base,index,scale)` in AT&T syntax. If both `index` and `scale` are empty, you can write `disp(base)` instead, otherwise just leave out the missing register (but keep the comma). Your instruction becomes

```
lea RTLWriteIntegerBuffer-1(%ecx),%edi
```

Note the swapped operands. In AT&T syntax, all two-argument opcodes have swapped operands except for some floating point instructions.

> ```
> LEA EBX,[EDX+'0']
> ```

Similarly, this one becomes

```
lea '0'(%edx),%ebx
```

> ```
> ReadCharInited: DB 0
> CMP BYTE PTR ReadCharInited,0
> ```

This one becomes

```
ReadCharInited: .byte 0
    cmpb $0,ReadCharInited
```

Note the `b` suffix indicating that this is a byte instruction. Other suffixes include `w` for *word*, `l` for *doubleword* (long) and  `q` for *quadword* (amd64 only). Immediates are prefixed with `$`, memory operands are unprefixed.

> Another question is: Is there 1:1 mapping between AT&T syntax and Intel syntax? Or are there specific Intel commands that are not supported in AT&T?

For instructions, there generally is. One way to figure this out is to write an instruction in Intel syntax and then dump it in AT&T syntax (with `objdump -d`) or vice versa (with `objdump -d -Mintel`).

For pseudo-instructions (such as `TIMES` or `DB`) there may not be as the UNIX assembler is conceptually different from e.g. masm.

> ```
> INVOKE HeapAlloc,EAX,HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS+HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY+HEAP_CREATE_ALIGN_16,4194332
> ```

Instead of this function, you might want to just use good old `calloc` from the C standard library. Something like this should work if you plan to link against the libc:

```
push $4194332
push $1
call calloc
add $8,%esp
```

Note though that there is no `HeapDestroy` or similar, you need to write your own allocator if you want this functionality.

Comment: In Windows, `calloc` and `malloc` are built on top of `HeapAlloc`, while `free` is built on top of `HeapFree`, using a private heap managed by the C runtime library. (`HeapFree` is the opposite of `HeapAlloc`; `HeapDestroy` is the opposite of `HeapCreate`.)  So yes, just call `calloc` and `free` in *nix.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there 1:1 mapping between AT&T syntax and Intel syntax? Or are there specific Intel commands that are not supported in AT&T?

Both syntaxes can express every form of every x86 instruction.  Any valid x86 machine-code can be disassembled into either AT&T, MASM, or NASM syntax.

There are some differences, though, so mapping mnemonics isn't exactly 1:1.  For example, in AT&T syntax, you have to use `movabs $0x123456789abcd, %rax` to get the encoding that uses a 64-bit immediate.

In NASM syntax, the assembler automatically picks the `mov r64, imm64` encoding vs. the `mov r/m32, imm32` or `mov r/m64, sign-extended-imm32` encoding based on the constant.  So `mov rax, 1` might assemble to a 5-byte `mov r32, imm32` or a 7 byte `mov r/m64, imm32` (which is why you should always write `mov eax, 1` to make sure you get the smaller encoding).  But `mov rax, 0x123456789abcd` will always assemble to the 10-byte `mov r64, imm64` form, without having to use a different mnemonic.

See [Intel's insn set ref for MOV](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html).  (Other links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki).

This archive.org copy of x86-64.org's [what's new in x86-64](http://web.archive.org/web/20160609221003/http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/assembly.html) also covers the movabs vs. mov mnemonic issue, and other stuff.

Comment: I did want to add for OP to this particular sub-question, that AT&T vs Intel maps basically 1:1 (as the x86 machine code is the x86 machine code, still the same). BUT as he's doing also 32b -> 64b conversion, he may hit particular 32b instructions which are no more valid in 64b mode, so in his case the 1:1 mapping may be broken due to 32->64 bit conversion.